# Caliburn.Micro .NET Standard, Xamarin.Forms (iOS and Android) Only, which .NET Standard version to target?

Tags: xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro, .net-standard

In order to properly run CM in a Xamarin Forms project using .Net Standard, what version of .NET Standard should I be targeting? I am currently targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and I'm getting the warning:

```
"Package 'Caliburn.Micro 4.0.0-alpha.1' was restored using 
  '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259, 
  .NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259, 
  .NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net45+win+win81+wp8+wpa81, 
  .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, 
  .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, 
  .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8'
  instead of the project target framework '
.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."
```

Should I be on .NET Standard 1.6 or 1.0? I've seen the following comment from Nigel:

Caliburn.Micro.Core can target .NET Standard 1.0 so lots of support there.
Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms will be 1.6.

However, since the forms project will pull in both of those packages in, I am confused as to which version I should target.

My project runs fine in the simulator but crashes on an iOS device. I'm thinking it has something to do with the warning above.

Thanks!

Sean

Comment: [version 4.0.105-alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro/4.0.105-alpha) supports .net standard 2.0, so update the nuget to the last prerelease version.

Comment: Thanks.. It wouldn't let me upgrade Caliburn.Micro without first upgrading Caliburn.Micro.Core. Now, that I have done both, I'm getting the following warning: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms 4.0.0-alpha.1 requires Caliburn.Micro.Core (= 4.0.0-alpha.1) but version Caliburn.Micro.Core 4.0.105-alpha was resolved." There is no 4.0.105 for Cal.Micro.Xamarin.Forms

Comment: ok, raise an issue for that on github issue tracker of the Caliburn project